# Uncertainty principle and Fock states

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, photons, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, photonics

While studying about single photon sources, I came across the following sentence on the related Wikipedia page

> The Heisenberg uncertainty principle dictates that a state with an exact number of photons of a single frequency cannot be created.

However isn't that precisely how a Fock state is defined? A fock state $|n⟩_{k, \epsilon}$ specifies the number or photons $n$ in the field mode given by $k$ and $\epsilon$ which are the wave vector (therefore frequency) and polarization respectively. Hence we would have a state with an exact number of photons and a single frequency, which according to my understanding can be realized within optical cavities with ease. Where is the discrepancy coming from?

Comment: A similar issue: you can define (with some mathematical gymnastics) $|x\rangle$ and $|p\rangle$ states in first-quantized QM, but the uncertainty principle says that we can't actually have a particle in either of those states.

Answer (score 3):

As a simpler case, think back to one-dimensional single-particle quantum mechanics.

In that context we have an uncertainty relation $\Delta x \Delta p \geq \hbar / 2$. And in that case, although we like to write things like "let $| k\rangle \in \mathcal{H}$ be a momentum eigenstate" this is sort of a polite fiction: really the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ is the space of all normalizable states, and $|k\rangle$ isn't normalizable. It's useful as a basis element, and you can certainly write honest physical states like $|\psi\rangle = \int dk \psi(k) |k\rangle$ with $\psi(k)$ some well-behaved function for which we can normalize (that is, we can compute $\int dk |\psi(k)|^2$), but $|k\rangle$ itself isn't a physical state.

The state $|n\rangle_{k, \epsilon}$ follows the same principle. It's not a normalizable state, hence not a physical one, but you can integrate it against some nice function of $k$ to get a physical one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That makes a lot of sense. I just had one follow up question. Aren't Fock states the exact solution to the Hamiltonian of an optical cavity? If they aren't physically realizable, then what is it that we really end up generating in cavities?

Comment: Also, another key difference that I'd want to point out is that a momentum eigenstate |k⟩  is not defined at a specific value of position, unlike the Fock state which needs a specific frequency in order to be defined in the first place.

Comment: @UVCatastrophe I guess you can't get true monochromatic modes in cavities, what u get is quasi-monochromatic modes. that is the distribution is not a true Dirac delta but a narrow gaussian.

Comment: @physshyp exactly - for improper states like this, you can generally say thing like "$| \alpha \rangle$ isn't a physical state, but I can find physical states $| \psi \rangle$ which are concentrated arbitrarily closely around $| \alpha \rangle$" and that's enough for many purposes.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you define "Fock space".

Photon sources actually create "wave packets".  Basically you have
$$
\hat A^{\dagger}(\alpha)=\int_0^{\infty} d\omega  \alpha(\omega)\hat a^\dagger(\omega)
$$
where $\hat a^\dagger(\omega)$ creates a photon of frequency $\omega$ and $\alpha(\omega)$ is a distribution of frequencies in your wave packet, normalized so that
\begin{align}
\int d\omega \vert\alpha(\omega)\vert^2=1\, .
\end{align}

A single photon state is then conventionally defined as
\begin{align}
\vert 1\rangle = \hat A^\dagger(\alpha)\vert 0\rangle
\end{align}

In the time domain we have
\begin{align}
\hat a^\dagger(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\omega \hat a^\dagger (\omega) e^{i\omega t}
\end{align}
and since $\hat a^\dagger (\omega)$ and $\hat a^\dagger(t)$ are connected via Fourier transform the usual relation $\Delta \omega\Delta t\approx 2\pi$ holds.

The physical interpretation is the same as the Fourier analysis of a signal: if the signal has very sharp frequency distribution around some $\omega_0$, it must have very long duration for the Fourier relation to hold.  Conversely, if the signal is very short, it will contain a broad distribution of frequencies.

See for instance

> Fearn H, Loudon R. Theory of two-photon interference. JOSA B. 1989 May 1;6(5):917-27

for some additional gory details.